# Issue saving generated image to local filesystem in iOS using Capacitor

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, capacitor

I'm working on an Ionic application with Capacitor, where I generate a chart using Highcharts and convert it to an image using html2canvas. My goal is to save this image to the local filesystem of the device, specifically on iOS.

I've implemented the following code in my application:

```
<ion-button (click)="downloadChartAsImage()">Descargar Gráfico</ion-button>

//metodo para descargar gráfico renderizado con highcharts
async downloadChartAsImage() {
  const chartContainer = document.getElementById('highchartsContainer');

  if (chartContainer) {
    try {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(chartContainer);
      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      if (Capacitor.isNative && Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
        // en dispositivos ios guardar la imagen en el sistema de archivos local
        const base64Data = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');

        const fileName = 'chart.png';

        const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: base64Data,
          directory: Directory.Documents
        });

        if (result && result.uri) {
          // notificar que la imagen se ha guardado
          console.log('Imagen guardada en el sistema de archivos local:', result.uri);

          // notificar al usuario que la imagen se ha guardado
          alert('Imagen guardada en el sistema de archivos local: ' + result.uri);
        } else {
          console.error('Error al guardar la imagen: No se devolvió una URI.');
        }

      } else {
        // en otros dispositivos, crear un enlace para la descarga de la imagen
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = imageData;
        a.download = 'chart.png';
        a.click();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al generar o guardar la imagen del gráfico:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('Contenedor del gráfico no encontrado.');
  }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that although the console shows me the URI of the file saved to the local filesystem (file://...), I can't find this image on the iOS simulated device. However, if I run the command open chart.png in the terminal, I can view the image correctly.

Is there something I'm overlooking or any additional configuration needed in iOS for the saved image to be accessible from the application?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried several troubleshooting steps to locate the saved image on the iOS device:

1.Verified the Filesystem Path: I've double-checked the path where the image is saved using Filesystem.writeFile() and confirmed that it matches the expected directory (Directory.Documents) and filename (chart.png).

2.Checked Application Sandbox: I've explored the application sandbox on the iOS simulator to manually search for the saved image file but couldn't locate it.

3.Tested Terminal Command: Running open chart.png in the terminal successfully opens the image, indicating that it exists in the filesystem.

I expected the saved image to be accessible within the application's sandbox directory on the iOS device, similar to how it's accessible via the terminal command. However, despite the successful save operation reported by Capacitor, I'm unable to locate the image within the application's filesystem.

Comment: Hi, you used the Highcharts tag, however, your question doesn't seem to be related to Highcharts itself. When it comes to the converting charts to images, consider using the Highcharts export server. You will find more information here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: Hi @magdalena

Thank you for your response. I appreciate your suggestion to use the Highcharts export server. However, I encountered some difficulties with it, particularly on iOS devices.When I followed the steps provided in the Highcharts iOS repository (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios) and the tutorial on their website (https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/create-charts-highcharts-ios/), I faced an issue where the menu with export options didn't open on iOS. I ensured that I followed all the steps correctly and properly configured my info.plist file for iOS.

Comment: Due to this issue, I decided to implement the chart-to-image conversion directly within the application using html2canvas and Capacitor. While this approach works well on Android devices, I encountered challenges with iOS.

If you have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve the issue with the Highcharts export server on iOS or any alternative solutions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your assistance.

Best regards,
@magdalena

Comment: It's difficult to say what might be causing that issue without seeing the code. However, I suspect it could be due to not setting the current View Controller for HIChartView: `chartView.viewController = self`. Please find an example demo using an export server at the following [link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues/351#issuecomment-741763433).